# Spring Boot JmsListener not reading from IBM MQ after service inactive for long periods (e.g. 1 month)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq

I am facing an issue where the listener is not reading messages from IBM MQ after the service being inactive for a long period, probably like a month or so. Below is a warning from Tomcat's log suggesting a memory leak with IBM MQ dependency: `mq-jms-spring-boot-starter`. Please suggest what can be done from my end.

- Java version: 8
- Spring Boot: 2.2.4.RELEASE
- `mq-jms-spring-boot-starter` 2.0.0

```
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 WARNING [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [psh-common-payment-service] appears to have started a thread named [JMSCCThreadPoolMaster] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
 com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$WorkQueueManagerThread.waitForNotification(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:672)
 com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$WorkQueueManagerThread.waitForNotification(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:641)
 com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$WorkQueueManagerThread.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:908)
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 WARNING [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [psh-common-payment-service] appears to have started a thread named [JMSCCThreadPoolWorker-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
 com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteReconnectThread.bestHconn(RemoteReconnectThread.java:654)
 com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteReconnectThread.run(RemoteReconnectThread.java:128)
 com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:319)
 com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:99)
 com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:343)
 com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:312)
 com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1227)
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls$1] (value [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls$1@6a0d4488]) and a value of type [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls] (value [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls@3bd064d9]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@5e40451f]) and a value of type [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiCodepage] (value [37(IBM037) Unmappable Action: REPORT Unmappable Replacement: 63]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@102a1e48]) and a value of type [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiComponentTls[]] (value [[Lcom.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiComponentTls;@100321c1]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@28cd69b4]) and a value of type [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiCodepage] (value [37(IBM037) Unmappable Action: REPORT Unmappable Replacement: 63]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls$1] (value [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls$1@6a0d4488]) and a value of type [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls] (value [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls@7479a90f]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@5e40451f]) and a value of type [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiCodepage] (value [37(IBM037) Unmappable Action: REPORT Unmappable Replacement: 63]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@28cd69b4]) and a value of type [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiCodepage] (value [37(IBM037) Unmappable Action: REPORT Unmappable Replacement: 63]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@102a1e48]) and a value of type [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiComponentTls[]] (value [[Lcom.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiComponentTls;@34612196]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls$1] (value [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls$1@6a0d4488]) and a value of type [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls] (value [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls@3de513f2]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@5e40451f]) and a value of type [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiCodepage] (value [37(IBM037) Unmappable Action: REPORT Unmappable Replacement: 63]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@28cd69b4]) and a value of type [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiCodepage] (value [37(IBM037) Unmappable Action: REPORT Unmappable Replacement: 63]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@102a1e48]) and a value of type [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiComponentTls[]] (value [[Lcom.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiComponentTls;@7ea65d33]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls$1] (value [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls$1@6a0d4488]) and a value of type [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls] (value [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls@472ea239]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@5e40451f]) and a value of type [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiCodepage] (value [37(IBM037) Unmappable Action: REPORT Unmappable Replacement: 63]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@28cd69b4]) and a value of type [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiCodepage] (value [37(IBM037) Unmappable Action: REPORT Unmappable Replacement: 63]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@102a1e48]) and a value of type [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiComponentTls[]] (value [[Lcom.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiComponentTls;@7afe56db]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls$1] (value [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls$1@6a0d4488]) and a value of type [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls] (value [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls@6f91b0f5]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@5e40451f]) and a value of type [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiCodepage] (value [37(IBM037) Unmappable Action: REPORT Unmappable Replacement: 63]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@28cd69b4]) and a value of type [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiCodepage] (value [37(IBM037) Unmappable Action: REPORT Unmappable Replacement: 63]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@102a1e48]) and a value of type [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiComponentTls[]] (value [[Lcom.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiComponentTls;@231227f1]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls$1] (value [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls$1@6a0d4488]) and a value of type [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls] (value [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls@111f76c0]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@5e40451f]) and a value of type [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiCodepage] (value [37(IBM037) Unmappable Action: REPORT Unmappable Replacement: 63]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@28cd69b4]) and a value of type [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiCodepage] (value [37(IBM037) Unmappable Action: REPORT Unmappable Replacement: 63]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@102a1e48]) and a value of type [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiComponentTls[]] (value [[Lcom.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiComponentTls;@195fb2b6]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls$1] (value [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls$1@6a0d4488]) and a value of type [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls] (value [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTls@7b2bbf70]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@102a1e48]) and a value of type [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiComponentTls[]] (value [[Lcom.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiComponentTls;@49b4324b]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Sep-2023 14:32:35.686 SEVERE [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [psh-common-payment-service] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@102a1e48]) and a value of type [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiComponentTls[]] (value [[Lcom.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiComponentTls;@23f7f4cb]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

I am not sure if the above error is causing this behavior or there are some other factors at play.